# Computing multiple correlation coefficient between first three PCA components and an additional variable

Tags: correlation, pca, matlab

This is follow-up from a previous question: [How to separate groups using PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/how-to-separate-groups-using-pca).

I have $25$ normals and $12$ patients. For each of them I have a vector representing a spectrogram (length $2000$).

So I have a matrix $Z$ of size $[25\times2000;12\times 2000]$.

I calculate:

```
[coeffZ, score, latent, tsquared, explained, mu]=pca(Z);
```

and `bar(explained)` shows me that the first $3$ PCs explain most of the variance.

I also have a behavioral score (from testing) for each of the subjects ($[37\times 1]$). It was suggested that I see if the first 3 PCs can predict the behavioral score using multiple correlation coefficient. Specifically this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation

Does this make sense? Does anybody have an idea of how I can implement this in Matlab?

Comment: What was the previous question. I don't understand this one.

Comment: @susan First: please add the link to your previous question. Second: this question is almost off-topic here, because you ask how to do something in a particular programming language (MATLAB). Please think how you can revise your question to make it more general and extend beyond a simple programming question.

Comment: Not sure but is it the same as regress? http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html?searchHighlight=regress

Comment: I think it is this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/coefficient-of-determination-r-squared.html?searchHighlight=coefficient+of+determination but I do not have the statistics toolbox

Comment: @susan: If you want somebody to receive your comments automatically, you should include `@ username` (without a space) somewhere in the comment. I noticed your comments only by chance (opened this question to check if there are new comments...). I can update my answer to address your your comments, but how did you run pca() if you don't have statistics toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question as it stands now is arguably off-topic, I will provide a quick answer.

There is no function in MATLAB to directly compute multiple correlation coefficient. In principle, you could either use multiple regression function [regress()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) to get $R^2$ and obtain your correlation coefficient $R$ with a square root, or canonical correlation function [canoncorr()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/canoncorr.html), which reduces to multiple correlation if one of the datasets consists of only single variable.

However, in your particular case three PCs are uncorrelated (it is a property of PCA), so square of the multiple correlation of your behavioural score with the three PCs is simply equal to the sum of squares of usual correlations between the behavioural score and each of the three PCs. So you can compute these three correlation coefficients, square them, add them up, take the square root, and you are done.

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly I just need to do sqrt[corr(score(:,1),beh)^2 + corr(score(:,2),beh)^2 + corr(score(:,3),beh)^2]

Comment: just making sure you see this: Yes, if I understand you correctly I just need to do sqrt[corr(score(:,1),beh)^2 + corr(score(:,2),beh)^2 + corr(score(:,3),beh)^2]

Comment: @susan: If you comment on my answer, then I will receive  notifications in any case :) Yes, the formula is correct.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to test the significance of the obtained R.I tried F ratio mentioned here - http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCC2007-pretty.pdf but they don't explain what the numbers mean :) i.e. what does an F ratio of 10.22 mean?

Comment: @susan: It's the value of F statistic, and it can be converted into a p-value. So if your F=10.22 and number of degrees of freedom is J=3 and N-J-1=37-3-1=33 (see the pdf you found), then you can calculate (e.g. here http://graphpad.com/quickcalcs/PValue1.cfm) that p<0.0001, i.e. highly significant.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. One more question. Can I assume that this general rule applies for multiple corelation?        If r = +.70 or higher Very strong positive relationship +.40 to +.69 Strong positive relationship +.30 to +.39 Moderate positive relationship +.20 to +.29 weak positive relationship +.01 to +.19 No or negligible relationship

Comment: @susan: I don't think "rules" like that are helpful. Which correlation is "strong" and which one is not, depends largely on your personal judgment and also on the particular dataset, problem, and situation. Plot your data (behavioural score vs. PC1, vs. PC2, and vs. PC3), look at it, and form an opinion about how strong the relationship looks to you, but don't rely on any general "rules". One important detail though: the signs of your PCs do not have any meaning, they are arbitrary. So your correlation can be positive or negative, it does not mean anything. Only the absolute value matters.

Comment: I am writing up this analysis and need to specify the significance test. I looked on graph pad website but don't see anything.Can you help? i.e. how would you describe: correlation -> f-statistic --> p value?

Comment: @user3361156, please merge your account here w/ the unregistered one you used above. Then register your account. You will be able to leave comments to answers to your own questions & will be notified of responses. You can find information about managing your accounts in our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @susan: I am not a big expert on multiple correlation, but I think that this stuff is pretty standard so you don't need to describe it in any particular detail. You would want to mention the value of your correlation coefficient, the F statistic and the p-value, e.g. "multiple correlation between this and that was $R^2=0.9$ ($F_{3,33}=10.22$, $p<0.0001$)".